# How to implement a plot of the regression model in my code?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I have a little school project and would like to show the plot of the function in any way, maybe like this:[image: Regression model]
I know that my code is probaply bad, and if you have any iprovements just throw them at me.

This is the code I have worked on so far... I coded the data into the program by hand.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import linear_model


Xtrain = np.array([[15, 15, 20, 30, 20, 20],
                   [10, 10, 15, 25, 15, 15],
                   [20, 20, 25, 35, 25, 25],
                   [20, 20, 30, 20, 30, 20],
                   [15, 15, 25, 15, 25, 15],
                   [25, 25, 35, 25, 35, 25],
                   [30, 30, 30, 30, 10, 10],
                   [25, 25, 25, 25, 10, 10],
                   [35, 25, 35, 35, 15, 15],
                   [20, 20, 30, 25, 30, 25],
                   [15, 15, 25, 20, 25, 20],
                   [25, 25, 35, 30, 35, 30],
                   [10, 10, 15, 25, 30, 20],
                   [10, 10, 10, 20, 25, 15],
                   [20, 20, 20, 30, 35, 25],
                   [20, 25, 25, 20, 30, 20],
                   [15, 20, 20, 15, 25, 15],
                   [25, 30, 30, 25, 35, 25]])

ytrain = np.array([20, 15, 25, 20, 15, 25, 15, 10, 20, 20, 15, 25, 15, 10, 20, 20, 15, 25])

lr = LogisticRegression().fit(Xtrain, ytrain)

yhat = lr.predict(Xtrain)

print (accuracy_score(ytrain, yhat))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your Xtrain (in other words your Xaxis) is composed of 6 variables. That means it is 6 dimensional. On top of that there is a Y dimension of ytrain. A total of 7 dimensions. It will be very hard to visualize 7 dimensions on a 2D diagram. However suppose you want to plot the first column in the Xtrain with respect to Ytrain and plot it on top of it the predicted yhat, you can do as below. However please note this will not serve your original purpose of plotting the full Xtrain.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Xtrain = np.array([[15, 15, 20, 30, 20, 20],
                   [10, 10, 15, 25, 15, 15],
                   [20, 20, 25, 35, 25, 25],
                   [20, 20, 30, 20, 30, 20],
                   [15, 15, 25, 15, 25, 15],
                   [25, 25, 35, 25, 35, 25],
                   [30, 30, 30, 30, 10, 10],
                   [25, 25, 25, 25, 10, 10],
                   [35, 25, 35, 35, 15, 15],
                   [20, 20, 30, 25, 30, 25],
                   [15, 15, 25, 20, 25, 20],
                   [25, 25, 35, 30, 35, 30],
                   [10, 10, 15, 25, 30, 20],
                   [10, 10, 10, 20, 25, 15],
                   [20, 20, 20, 30, 35, 25],
                   [20, 25, 25, 20, 30, 20],
                   [15, 20, 20, 15, 25, 15],
                   [25, 30, 30, 25, 35, 25]])

ytrain = np.array([20, 15, 25, 20, 15, 25, 15, 10, 20, 20, 15, 25, 15, 10, 20, 20, 15, 25])

lr = LogisticRegression().fit(Xtrain, ytrain)

yhat = lr.predict(Xtrain)

plt.scatter(x=Xtrain[:,0],y=ytrain,color="blue")
plt.scatter(x=Xtrain[:,0],y=yhat,color="red")
plt.show()
```

The output is as below. The predicted and observed values are very close in this case. Please let me know, if my explanation made any sense or if I read the problem requirement completely wrong.

[image: The output of plotting 1 variable from Xtrain]

Comment: Basically that answers my question in one way, but I thought about just plotting a function of the model. I see the problem with the many dimensions. I thank you for the reply @Amit